# Excel export: browser hangs up

Tags: php, linux, excel

I use this http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ to export to excel.

need to export 11000 - 65000 rows...
but when trying to do this browser hangs up.
it do not answer with errors or other messages. just show that request in progress.

top shows that apache finished work.
even apache log says that all done:

```
x.x.x.x - - [28/Jul/2011:12:28:38 +0300] "POST /doctor/lab/statistic/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2773504 "http://x.x.x.x:82/doctor/lab/statistic/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0"
```

but still no results.

system:

```
Linux Eearth 2.6.34-12-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2010-06-29 02:39:08 +0200 i686
PHP Version 5.3.5
Apache/2.2.15 (Linux/SUSE)
```

so the question

**EDIT 1**

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xls, 'Excel5');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit;
```

**EDIT 2**

i tried to save data to file like this `$writer->save('test.xls');` filesize 2.7MB
then if i do this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
include 'test.xls';
exit;
```

download starts immediate...

Comment: Try removing the exit; command

Comment: @Trefex this code is a part of framework. if i remove exit - many other data will attached and i don`t think this is solution

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your web server is not emitting error messages, so I'd say check your error.log (should be hanging around in /var/log/apache2 or similar.) It might well be something trivial like not being able to write to a temporary file.

If that turns out as a dead-end, consider programmatically creating CSV files with echo statements - Excel will open those just fine.

**EDIT**

To produce CSV, do your headers

```
header('Content-Type: text/comma-separated-values);
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'.$filename.'.csv"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

Then output your column headers:

```
echo "col1,col2,col3,col4,..."
```

followed by a new line. Then output your data:

```
while(/*Still got some rows*/) {
   echo $row[0] . "," .$row[1] "," + ...
}
```

Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values, it's a really simple file format and Excel will open it without difficulty.

The other thing, which I hadn't thought of, is if you've got access to a Windows Server, you can produce Excel files directly via COM interop.

Comment: 1. as i write above, server say that he(server) done his job correctly (error_log empty) and return all requested data. 2. there are no writing of temporary files just sending out. see edit1 above

Comment: Try "**flush()**"ing the output, maybe the **exit;** is just killing the script before the result gets sent...

Comment: does not help... it seams that on small sizes (2000 - 3000 excell rows) works

Comment: In which case, if you're just emitting the data, it seems that CSV might be a better option.

Comment: lost conversation thread %-) you propose replace excell export to csv? it is a bed idea. there are html table witch converting to .xls.

Comment: The key is that if you're just *producing* Excel data, there's a 90% solution via CSV. Provided you have the data used to produce the HTML table, it should be quite simple to hook up. If you've got complicated stuff like merged cells and highlighted rows and columns, then I've misunderstood the requirements. If that's the case, you could probably try hacking in an ob_flush when it gets to around 2000 rows.

Comment: decided to reject phpexcell because of bad memory organization. thnx for your attention to my question